# Display the current week days and with date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

I have a bit of a problem. I want that i display all the days with date in the current week (as i'm writing it's week 38 (Gregorian)). What i have is good but, it doesnt display the correct days. For example:
This week the monday is 15th of September and sunday is 21th of September.
When i set the the first day of the week it sets it as sunday 14th of September.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *myCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *currentComps = [myCalendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:currentDate];
int thisWeeksNumber = currentComps.weekOfYear;
NSLog(@"1  %d", thisWeeksNumber); //This displays the correct week.

[currentComps setWeekday:1];
NSDate *firstDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];
[currentComps setWeekday:2];
NSDate *secondDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];
[currentComps setWeekday:3];
NSDate *thirdDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];
[currentComps setWeekday:4];
NSDate *fourthDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];
[currentComps setWeekday:5];
NSDate *fifthDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];
[currentComps setWeekday:6];
NSDate *sixthDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];
[currentComps setWeekday:7];
NSDate *seventhDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];

NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
myDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSString *firstStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *secondStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:secondDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *thirdStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:thirdDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *fourthStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:fourthDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *fifthStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:fifthDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *sixthStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:sixthDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *seventhStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:seventhDayOfTheWeek];

NSLog(@"\n %@ \n %@ \n %@ \n %@ \n %@ \n %@ \n %@", firstStr, secondStr, thirdStr, fourthStr, fifthStr, sixthStr, seventhStr);
```

This should display 15th of september to 21th of september but it displays 14th of september(sunday) to 21th of September(saturday).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation it does exactly what it should do:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateComponents/setWeekday:

When you call `setWeekDay` - 1 means Sunday, so if you need to start with Monday your first call should be `setWeekDay:2`

Update:

As for going and getting all consecutive days after the first one I would suggest implementing something like that (insert this function into your code):

```
- (NSDate*)dateByAddingDays:(NSInteger)days toDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    comps.day = days;

    return [calendar dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: date options: 0];
}
```

And use this function to add 1-6 from the day you begin your week. Basically replacing all second and other days code:

```
[currentComps setWeekday:2];
NSDate *secondDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];
```

with the following:

```
NSDate *secondDayOfTheWeek = [self dateByAddingDays:1 toDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];
NSDate *thirdOfTheWeek = [self dateByAddingDays:2 toDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];
...
```

Comment: Yes, i've tried that. But how do i get the sunday 21th of September? Cuz' a week doesn't start with a sunday.

Comment: I have no idea how i should implement this in my code.

Comment: @Dridia: I added exact code that you need to copy-paste to your code.

Comment: I have no idea how you did this @sha ! But i works like a charm! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Today (sunday) This code execute next weeks days. So, today it's still week 38, but it display all the dates of week 39. Why is that so?